# Adding a total from a for loop python

Tags: python

I'm trying to print an individual number produced by each individual plant in the list named "PLANTS" and then add those numbers to a total in python.

Currently that total is reset every time the for loop runs again.

```
def rainfall_food_calculator(rainfall, food, days):
    half_rainfall = random.randint(round(rainfall / 2), rainfall) / 100
    for plant in PLANTS:
        print(f"{plant} produced {round(half_rainfall * len(plant))}", end=", ")
        food += round(half_rainfall * len(plant))
    if rainfall < 30:
        random_plant = random.choice(PLANTS)
        PLANTS.remove(random_plant)
        print(f"Sadly your {random_plant} plant has died")
    print(f"After {days} days, you have {len(PLANTS)} plants and your total food is {food}")
```

For example the for loop might run and get this output:

```
Parsley produced 5, Sage produced 3, Rosemary produced 5, Thyme produced 3, After 1 days, you have 4 plants and your total food is 16
```

and then run a second time and reset the total food and give this output:

```
Parsley produced 3, Sage produced 1, Rosemary produced 3, Thyme produced 2, After 2 days, you have 4 plants and your total food is 9
```

I want to add each individual number to an overall total that is added upon every time the for loop runs.

Comment: And you don't do that because ...?

Answer (score 0):

The function you have there doesn't return anything you're just print a sentence out so you have no memory of it. Your function currently just does some maths and prints things out and doesn't save your logic anywhere.

If you create a variable called plantInformation just as an example. Set this to be equal to what you have in the print and return plantInformation you can have this variable after you've ran your function.

As an example (I don't have a python editor on this laptop so apologies if the syntax isn't 100% correct)

```
def rainfall_food_calculator(rainfall, food, days):
    half_rainfall = random.randint(round(rainfall / 2), rainfall) / 100
    for plant in PLANTS:
        print(f"{plant} produced {round(half_rainfall * len(plant))}", end=", ")
        food += round(half_rainfall * len(plant))
    if rainfall < 30:
        random_plant = random.choice(PLANTS)
        PLANTS.remove(random_plant)
        print(f"Sadly your {random_plant} plant has died")
    plantInformation = (f"After {days} days, you have {len(PLANTS)} plants and your 
    total food is {food}")

    return plantInformation
```

You'll have to change your function slightly so when you run it again it takes into account plantInformation now. If you think about your code it has no idea (no variables have been passed in) of how many plants were alive before.

What I would suggest is have a little read up on python dictionaries. Dictionaries can be used to store information and would be useful for this problem. You can use dictionaries to store lots of data (such as plant populations) so when you run your function again it knows how many plants are currently alive.

Comment: I should have added sorry. As a rule of thumb you don't usually want functions to print things out. You want them to return a variable which you can print out later in the code. The reason for this is it makes it a lot easier to debug and if someone else uses your code they can get values out of your functions. I'm guessing you're quite new to Python so it's not the end of the world but is good practice to get into.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it didn't work. It doesn't even display the plantinfomation sentence now. Also the problem wasn't that print line it was the fact that food wasn't actually being added up to a total. If I take all that code and put it in the main() function where 'food' is being declared it works fine but I'm trying to keep it in a separate function.

Comment: My other thought was to make another list that corresponds to the population of each plant? So you have 3 plants so far, create a list like totalPopulation=[0,0,0] and then add the plants produced each run of the function to the relevant spot in the list. It's not the most elegant way and I'm sure there is a better way but it could work for now until you can sort it out?